# Cannot Build kafka-connect-jdbc Source Code

Tags: java, maven, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

The `mvn install` command fails and I am unable to build the kafka-connect-jdbc source code. My intention is to modify the kafka-connect-jdbc source code.

I followed the instructions
https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc/issues/456
and
https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc/wiki/FAQ

All of which do not solve the problem. Can someone please assist?

*Error Message (Snippet)*

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) on project kafka-connect-jdbc: Compilation failure: Compilation failure: 
[ERROR] /java/projects/kafka-connect-jdbc/src/main/java/io/confluent/connect/jdbc/dialect/SqlServerDatabaseDialect.java:[19,38] package org.apache.kafka.common.config does not exist
[ERROR] java/projects/kafka-connect-jdbc/src/main/java/io/confluent/connect/jdbc/dialect/SqlServerDatabaseDialect.java:[20,37] package org.apache.kafka.connect.data does not exist
[ERROR] /java/projects/kafka-connect-jdbc/src/main/java/io/confluent/connect/jdbc/dialect/SqlServerDatabaseDialect.java:[21,37] package org.apache.kafka.connect.data does not exist
[ERROR] /java/projects/kafka-connect-jdbc/src/main/java/io/confluent/connect/jdbc/dialect/SqlServerDatabaseDialect.java:[22,37] package org.apache.kafka.connect.data does not exist
[ERROR] /java/projects/kafka-connect-jdbc/src/main/java/io/confluent/connect/jdbc/dialect/SqlServerDatabaseDialect.java:[23,37] package org.apache.kafka.connect.data does not exist
[ERROR] /java/projects/kafka-connect-jdbc/src/main/java/io/confluent/connect/jdbc/dialect/DatabaseDialectProvider.java:[19,38] package org.apache.kafka.common.config does not exist
[ERROR] /java/projects/kafka-connect-jdbc/src/main/java/io/confluent/connect/jdbc/dialect/GenericDatabaseDialect.java:[19,38] package org.apache.kafka.common.config does not exist
[ERROR] /java/projects/kafka-connect-jdbc/src/main/java/io/confluent/connect/jdbc/dialect/GenericDatabaseDialect.java:[20,44] package org.apache.kafka.common.config.types does not exist

Comment: `org.apache.kafka.... does not exist` would imply that you didn't build the Kafka source code (using Gradle)

Answer (score 0):

Download kafka source libraries into your maven local repo and retry it should work.

Answer (score 0):

The master version of kafka-connect-jdbc depends on snapshot libraries not available on the central maven repository.

Make sure to clone locally:

- https://github.com/confluentinc/common.git : use `mvn clean install`
- https://github.com/apache/kafka.git : use `./gradlew installAll`

After successfully performing these steps proceed to build/modify locally kafka-connect-jdbc

Answer (score 0):

Go to [FAQ](http://%20https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc/wiki/FAQ) and than you will have information that you must :

```
Kafka - clone https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka.git and build with ./gradlew installAll
Common - clone https://github.com/confluentinc/common and build with mvn install
```